# How to properly line up 4 screens (two stacked rows) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have a quad-monitor setup (two stacked rows of two monitors) and a PC running Windows 10.

## Problem

The problem is that the intersection point of the monitors never lines up perfectly. The four screens are identical and I fiddled with the display arrangement *extensively*, but regardless of how much I play with it, there always seems to be a gap (as shown in the second picture below).

The thick black line shows the separation between the top left and bottom left screens. What it doesn't show is that the bottom left and right screens are also slightly offset from their top counterparts. The right side of the bottom left screen is at the light grey outline of the dark grey window, while the top left screen's right side is shown by the faint change in blue tones.

The second image of the intersection highlights the bad separation in red (emphasis of intersection problem in dark red) and the good display junctions in green. The top screens both need to move left and the top left screen needs to move down. Easy in theory, impossible in practice?

[image: Picture of display settings]
[image: Intersection of multi-display]
[image: Intersection of multi-display outlined]

---

## Question

How can I remove this gap?

Comment: You do it more carefully. My eyes can see there is a slight issue where you've placed Monitor 2 just to the right of its proper line up, and this is confirmed in your other image. Often I find it helpful to move one of the monitor icons in this tool to a completely different location and then rearrange the rest around it again.

Comment: Thank you @music2myear. Unfortunately, even if I do manage to line them up exactly perfectly, when I click "Apply" the displays move ever so slightly to set them just off one another.

Comment: Delete and reinstall the graphics driver?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with my LG monitor that lets you do a 4 way split. It takes forever sometimes a couple hours to get them just right. I've scoured the web looking for an easier way, but can't find much info on this either. It is a real pain and Microsoft should look into fixing this as sometimes you try to adjust and the snap in feature knocks it all back again. I finally got mine set, but literally there is no quick path other than trying to rearrange and snap them in again.

I have noticed that I can hold the shift key down and use the arrow keys to move them in smaller steps, but even with this, it still doesn't always get them where you need them to be.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've got this as close as it can be. Even with the pixels aligned perfectly it can snag on the corner if you are moving the mouse diagonally but it's a massive improvement from anything I could configure with the Windows UI.

Download a program that lest you save the config to a text file, like this one from Nirsoft https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html
Edit the PositionX and PositionY coordinates to the exact pixel you need for it to line up.
Load this edited config.

If there is a built in windows way of editing this config, maybe the registry, I'd be interested to know.